# How/where to deploy my webapp on my own server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, webserver

I have a built small web app using Java/J2ee. I want to host it myself in my own servers (I have none now). I have already downloaded Ubuntu Server OS. I prefer to host my app on my own servers (preferably using Linux, Apache and MySQL) rather than google app engine or any other hosting service?

1. Can some one guide me to look for server
   hardware?
2. Where should I buy them?
3. What sort of things I should look
   for in webserver hardware?
4. Which is cheaper, hosting on 3rd party
   servers or our own servers?
5. Can you provide some links where I can learn about creating webapps and hosting on our own servers?

Comment: maybe ask this over on serverfault.com too?  Seems like more of a hardware audience over there.

Comment: Nice idea, indeed, but: 'This site is currently in private beta testing.' [serverfault.com]

Answer (score 0):

The software you list can run on virtually any computer hardware, your requirements and intended use/target audience would be the starting point to assess what kind of hardware you need for scalability.

If it's for learning purposes or development just run it on your own pc or get the cheapest hosting account you can find.

Additional info needed to properly suggest anything.

Comment: actaully, I wanted to learn how to buy a dedicated server,configure it myself and run my webapp. Then, I will learn step by step about all the scalability and other issues later when i meet them... And i am new bee to this webapp thing, so i dont know what other info i should give. all i know is my webapp wont receive much audience atleast for now. So the thrill is setting up this thing and make it work. I have tested it with my own home PC. Now i want to buy sever and domain and host it myself. Thats why i asked for suggestions in this site  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host app for testing/trial purposes, go for for google app engine or 3rd party cheap shared hosting. If you are looking for reliable hosting or dedicated server, it is better to go for grid hosting providers such as media temple.

I would not suggest hosting app on your own servers. Running own servers is overhead and comes along with its own set of maintenance problems. Instead going for reliable hosting provider is a smart move.

Some of web hosting providers you can look for..

- MediaTemple ( Highly recommended )
- GoDaddy
- Blue Host
- DreamHost

Comment: actaully, I wanted to learn how to buy a dedicated server,configure it myself and run my webapp. Then, I will learn step by step about all the scalability and other issues later when i meet them... And i am new bee to this webapp thing, so i dont know what other info i should give. all i know is my webapp wont receive much audience atleast for now. So the thrill is setting up this thing and make it work. I have tested it with my own home PC. Now i want to buy sever and domain and host it myself. Thats why i asked for suggestions in this site :)

Comment: Whats the difference between grid service and other service provided at media temple

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see if you can get hold of a copy of [Professional Apache Tomcat 6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471753610) , which gives good advice on administering Apache (both web-server, and tomcat).